# Including or appending many php pages using jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with a `div` tag like this

```
<div class="ajax-load">

<!-- First.php: jquery-slider-1
            jquery-widget-1

    second.php: jquery-slider-2
                jquery-widget-2
 -->

</div>
```

And a `button` like this

```
<button class="go-to-page-2">
```

When I click the `button with class go-to-page2` I need to load some php pages say `four.php and five.php` into or inside the `div with class ajax-load.`

Using plain `markup`, I can easily place it like this

```
<?php
    require_once("four.php");
    require_once("five.php");
?>
```

But I do not want this. I want to `load contents into the div using ajax.` 
I tried this:

```
 $(".ajax-load").load("4.php")
```

But cant load or append 5.php using this. How to overcome this? I am ready to use `$.get and $.post`

Comment: `"But cant load or append 5.php using this"` - Why not?  What prevents you from loading content in this manner?

Comment: When I append 5.php to 4.php, 5.php wont get diplayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.load()` replaces the contents of the target element with whatever you loaded. You'd need to load page4, then APPEND page5, e.g.

```
$(".ajax-load").load("4.php");
$.get('5.php', function(data) {
   $('.ajax-load').innerHTML += data;
});
```

As well, note that since this will involve TWO separate http requests, there is NO guarantee as to which of the two requests will come back first. If loading 4.php before 5.php is absolutely critical, you'll have to chain the requests to so that the request for 5.php goes out only after 4.php has completed.

Comment: I don't think you mean `.innerHTML .= data;`.  probably `.append(data);`

Comment: Whoops, right. should be `+=`. been in a PHP mindset for the last while. thanks.

Comment: Thanks Marc! BTW why doesn't the javascript code does not work on appended data?

Comment: `.innerHTML` can't be used on a jQuery object, so the `+=` would still give an error, right?  I haven't looked at it in awhile, but either `append` or `$('.ajax-load').html($('.ajax-load').html() + data);`

Comment: `.html()` would just return the .innerHTML anyways. you can't concatenate with that and have it get assigned back into the dom node. jquery is just wrapping the existing dom interface on the elements, and part of each of those elements is .innerHTML anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You can just `$.get` and append to the html

```
$.get('5.php', function(data) {
  $('.ajax-load').append(data);
});
```

If you want `4.php` to load first, do the two of them in a nested way:

```
$.get('4.php', function(data) {... $.get('5.php', ...) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.get instead.

```
$.get('4.php', function(data) {
$('.ajax-load').prepend(data); //ensure this is appended before 5.php
});
$.get('5.php', function(data) {
$('.ajax-load').append(data); //ensure this is appended after 4.php
});
```

it's not perfect, though. It will execute as two separate async ajax requests.
You can use $.Deferred for that, or use a ajax callback (see w00d's answer).